# Binding variable from an ObservableObject cannot produce animation when changing the value

Tags: swift, swiftui, observableobject, swiftui-animation

I have a `List` view created from an integer array called `data` and use binding to pass the data to the view. I am using `withAnimation` when appending elements to the `data` array.

If the property wrapper of `data` is `@State`, shown below, then the animation will be played correctly when appending elements:

```swift
struct MyApp: App {
    @State var data: [Int] = Array(1...5)
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(data: $data)
        }
    }
}
```

However, If I place the `data` array into a class conforms to `ObservableObject`, the animation will not be played at all when appending elements:

```swift
class MyData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: [Int] = Array(1...5)
}

struct MyApp: App {
    @ObservedObject var data: MyData = MyData()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(data: $data.data)
        }
    }
}
```

#### Questions

1. Is my code correct? Or is it a bug of SwiftUI?
2. In the second situation, how can I correctly show the animation when appending to the array using `ObservableObject`?

#### ContentView.swift

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var data: [Int]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Button {
                withAnimation {
                    data.append(data.count + 1)
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Append an Item")
            }
            ForEach(data, id: \.self) { number in
                Text(String(number))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to change `ObservedObject` to `StateObject`

Answer (score 0):

try the following code :

```
class TestViewModel : ObservableObject{
    @Published var data: [Int] = Array(1...5)
}

struct TestView: View {
    
    @StateObject
    var vm = TestViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Button {
                withAnimation {
                    vm.data.append(vm.data.count + 1)
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Append an Item")
            }
            ForEach(vm.data, id: \.self) { number in
                Text(String(number))
            }
        }
    }
}
```